# AVA0: Get avalon read got err 0

Tags: cgminer

I am trying to connect my Avalon Controller to my Raspberry Pi (raplacing the TP-Link module with an Raspberry Pi)

When I use:

```
cgminer -o uk1.ghash.io:3333 -O x.x:x -D --verbose --avalon-options 115200:16:10:45:1024:55 --api-allow "W:127.0.0.1" --api-listen
```

I get an error like:

```
AVA0: Get avalon read got err 0
```

Someone can help me with this?

Here is the cgminer log:

```
 [2014-01-30 13:41:59] Started cgminer 3.8.5
 [2014-01-30 13:41:59] USB scan devices: checking for AVA devices
 [2014-01-30 13:41:59] RES: thread starting
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] AVA looking for and found BTB 0403:6001
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] USB lock avalon 1-6
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] RES: avalon (1:6) lock=1
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] USB res lock avalon 1-6
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] RES: avalon (1:6) lock ok=1
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] USB init, iManufacturer mismatch - BTB device 1:6
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] Found FTDI vs Burnin Electronics
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] USB free BTB
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] USB init, iManufacturer mismatch - BBF device 1:6
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] Found FTDI vs Burnin Electronics
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] USB free BBF
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] USB init - AVA device 1:6 usbver=0200 prod='FT232R USB UART' manuf='FTDI' serial='A801XEE2'
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] AVA0: reset got err 0
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] AVA0: latency got err 0
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] AVA0: data got err 0
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] AVA0: setbaud got err 0
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] AVA0: setmodemctrl got err 0
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] AVA0: setflowctrl got err 0
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] AVA0: setmodemctrl 2 got err 0
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] AVA0: setflowctrl 2 got err 0
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] Avalon: Sent(1):
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] 00000000   ad                                               |.               |
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] AVA0: usb_write got err 0
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] AVA0: Get avalon read got err 0
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] AVA0 reset: get:
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] 00000000   aa 55 aa 55 00 00 00 00  d0 1f 69 01 70 94 06 00 |.U.U......i.p...|
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] 00000010   d0 1f 69 01 34 9a 06 00  d0 9a 06 00 80 43 69 01 |..i.4........Ci.|
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] 00000020   80 43 69 01 00 cc f2 b6  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 |.Ci.............|
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] 00000030   70 94 06 00 d0 1f 69 01  d0 9a 06 00 38 52 02 00 |p.....i.....8R..|
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] AVA0: Reset failed! not an Avalon? (8: aa 55 aa 55)
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] Avalon: Sent(96):
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] 00000000   ac 20 2d 10 0b 00 40 1f  74 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 |. -...@.t.......|
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] 00000010   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................|
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] 00000020   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................|
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] 00000030   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 99 99 99 19 |................|
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] 00000040   32 33 33 33 cb cc cc 4c  64 66 66 66 fd ff ff 7f |2333...Ldfff....|
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] 00000050   96 99 99 99 2f 33 33 b3  c8 cc cc cc 61 66 66 e6 |..../33.....aff.|
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] AVA0: usb_write got err 0
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] Avalon: Sent(96):
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] 00000000   a4 20 2d 10 0b 00 40 1f  74 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 |. -...@.t.......|
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] 00000010   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................|
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] 00000020   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |................|
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] 00000030   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 99 99 99 19 |................|
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] 00000040   32 33 33 33 cb cc cc 4c  64 66 66 66 fd ff ff 7f |2333...Ldfff....|
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] 00000050   96 99 99 99 2f 33 33 b3  c8 cc cc cc 61 66 66 e6 |..../33.....aff.|
 [2014-01-30 13:42:00] AVA0: usb_write got err 0
```